# When would default case in switch for sealed hierarchy be invoked

Tags: java, switch-statement, java-21

Given a `sealed` hierarchy as below

```
sealed interface Shape permits Rectangle, Square

record Rectangle() implements Shape

record Square() implements Shape
```

Since `Rectangle` & `Square` are records, it inherently makes the whole hierarchy non-extensible i.e. no more subclasses are allowed any more.

Starting JDK 21, pattern matching for `switch` enforces switch to be exhaustive either by covering all possible `case` or by providing a `default` case to cover the remaining.

Thus, for below `switch` under what circumstances `default` case would be executed as all possible combinations are covered and why is it even permitted?

```
switch (shape) {
    case Rectangle r -> // do something with r;
    case Square sq -> // do something with sq; 
    case null -> // shape could be null 
    default -> // WHY is this permitted when all possible cases are covered already??
    }
```

**P.S.**: The sealed hierarchy definitely can evolve, but when that happens compiler will automatically flag the `switch` to upgrade itself too.

Comment: basically because it is not specified to be disallowed in the Java Language Specification - Why that is so? Firstly the developers/specifiers must be asked about that. Maybe because what would happen if the `switch` statement/expression is in a complete different compilation unit as the `Shape` class, that is, `Shape` can be changed/compiled with the first not being touched or even known to the compiler || BTW `i += 0` is also allowed ...

Comment: Good question. To second what @user85421 pointed out, the [JEP-441](https://openjdk.org/jeps/441) states the following -
*Again, the notion of exhaustiveness is an approximation. Because of separate compilation, it is possible for a novel implementation of the interface I to show up at runtime, so the compiler will in this case insert a synthetic default clause that throws.
The notion of exhaustiveness is made more complicated by record patterns (JEP 440) since record patterns can be nested. Accordingly, the notion of exhaustiveness must reflect this potentially recursive structure.*

Comment: So essentially things boil down to edge cases, for which explicit `default` can act as a safety net. Thanks for insights @user85421 & @Naman

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answers so far are mostly correct, but there is more to the story.

The simple answer given so far -- which is that there might be runtime values that match no case, regardless of compile-time type checking for exhaustiveness -- are correct.  A default clause is allowed because it is possible that it is selected (and if you don't provide one, the compiler gives you a synthetic one that throws MatchException.)

There are two primary reasons why a switch that is exhaustive at compile time might not be truly exhaustive at runtime: separate compilation, and remainder.

Separate compilation has been treated adequately in the other answers; novel enum constants and novel subtypes of sealed types can show up at runtime, because it is possible to recompile the hierarchy without recompiling switches over it.  This is normally handed silently for you by the compiler (there's no point in making you declare a `default` clause that just throws "can't get here"), but you can handle it yourself if you want.

The second reason is *remainder*, which reflects the fact that the reasonable meaning of "exhaustive enough" and actual exhaustiveness do not fully coincide, and if we demanded that switches be truly exhaustive, it would be very unfun to program in.

A simple example is this:

```
Box<Box<String>> bbs = ...
switch (bbs) { 
    case Box(Box(String s)): ...
}
```

Should this switch be exhuastive on `Box<Box<String>>`?  As it turns out, there is one possible value at runtime it does not match: `Box(null)`.  (Recall that nested patterns match the outer pattern, and then use the bindings of the outer pattern as match candidates for the inner pattern -- and a record pattern cannot match null, because it wants to invoke the component accessors.)

We could demand that to be exhaustive, there be a separate error handling case for `Box(null)`, but no one would like that, and with less trivial examples, the error handling would overwhelm the useful cases.  So Java makes the pragmatic choice of defining switch exhaustiveness in "human" terms -- the code that seems exhaustive for the reasonable classes -- and allowing for the "silly" cases to be handled by the synthetic default.  (You are still free to handle any silly cases explicitly if you want.)  This switch is considered exhaustive, but with non-empty remainder.

This whole concept is explained in greater detail in [Patterns: Exhaustiveness, Unconditionality, and Remainder](https://openjdk.org/projects/amber/design-notes/patterns/exhaustiveness).

Answer (score 3):

> The sealed hierarchy definitely can evolve, but when that happens compiler will automatically flag the switch to upgrade itself too.

This is not true. You seem to be assuming that both the switch statement and the records/sealed interfaces will always be compiled together. Of course, this will likely be true in most practical situations, but it is not *always* true. You can compile the sealed interfaces and records without recompiling the switch statement.

For example, suppose the types are all in separate .java files named with their names, so Shape.java, Rectangle.java, Square.java, while the switch statement is in the `main` method in Main.java.

First, I compile all the Java source files I have, and produces .class files for every .java file.

Then, suppose I change Shape.java to:

```
sealed interface Shape permits Rectangle, Square, Triangle
```

and added a Triangle.java file.

After that, I will compile just the records and the sealed interface, without compiling  Main.java. This is possible, because they don't depend on Main.java.

Finally, I run `java Main`. This will run the Main.class file, which doesn't know about the new `Triangle` class, because it was compiled before I added `Triangle`.

This is where the `default` branch will be executed, or if you don't have a `default` branch, this is where a `MatchException` will be thrown.

(Note that the `MatchException` part only applies to switch expressions and the [enhanced switch statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11.2), like the one in your question. Non-enhanced switch statements simply don't do anything if no cases match.)

See also [Execution of a switch Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11.3) and [Run-Time Evaluation of switch Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28.2) in the Java Language Specification.